# Visually Design Xamarin Apps

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I recently installed Visual Studio 2017 (with Xamarin) to build a simple app. Is there a way to visually design XAML front end files the same as we design android studio AXML files? By visually design I mean drag and drop predefined tools from toolbox (the same as form applications) and then build the backend and even handlers in the C# (see attached image). It does seem it is possible in visual studio to design apps but again it's only for AXML but not XAML. Any help on how to design (not code) the front end using Xamarin is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: no, there is not a drag-and-drop designer for Xamarin Forms (XAML)

Comment: I decided to migrate to another software named Kony. It seems to be quite capable and much easier to use than Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to drag and drop for design the xaml view in visual studio and visual studio for mac. The best you can have now is a xaml preview or gorilla player (preview in devices)